# Why is type inference not working in this switch statement in Swift 3?

Tags: swift

**UPDATE** This is fixed in Swift 3.1

In migrating an `if-else` to a `switch` statement, I noticed that type inference wasn't working. Why do I need to specify `HKQuantityTypeIdentifier` in each `case` when `quantityTypeIdentifier` is already of that type?

```
func process(samples: [HKSample]?, quantityTypeIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in            
        if let quantitySamples = samples as? [HKQuantitySample] {
            for sample in quantitySamples {
                switch quantityTypeIdentifier {
                case HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.distanceWalkingRunning:
                    // code

                case HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.activeEnergyBurned:
                    // code

                case HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.heartRate:
                    // code

                default:
                    fatalError("Quantity Type Identifier not implemented \(quantityTypeIdentifier)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to call the function like:

```
process(samples: samples, quantityTypeIdentifier: .distanceWalkingRunning)
```

Comment: `HKQuantityTypeIdentifier` is not an enum type. It's a struct. That's probably the reason.

Comment: I haven't been able to find anything in the Swift book, but it seems to me that if `if quantityTypeIdentifier == .distanceWalkingRunning {}` works, then the switch statement should be able to handle it too.

Comment: Is the reason this `struct` is not an `enum` for compatibility with Obj-C?

Comment: @jjatie I've deleted my comment because my explanation was inaccurate, but I still believe it's a compiler bug and that you should report to Apple. As you say yourself, I believe that if it works with `if` it should also work with `switch`.

Comment: @EricAya I'll file one now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've found a bug, or at least you have a reasonable case to claim one. The inconsistency is nicely shown by a much shorter example:

```
let c : UIColor = .red
switch c {
case .red : print ("red") // error
default : break
}
```

That won't compile. You can say `.red` on the first line but not on the third line. That seems a clear inconsistency.

Now, having said that, I can certainly explain why the rules are different in the two different places. A `case` expression is resolved according to the `~=` operator and the rules of forming a *pattern*. Those rules are different from anything else in Swift (hence, for example, there are situations where you say `as` in a `case` pattern but would say `as?` everywhere else). So evidently those are the rules that would need tweaking in order for this to work. They have been tweaked so far as to allow bare enum cases but not bare enum-like struct "cases" (that is, static members of structs that are RawRepresentable where those static members evaluate to an instance of the struct itself).

Finally, here's a skanky workaround that I like to use when `case` patterns become too onerous:

```
let c : UIColor = .red
switch true {
case c == .red : print ("red") // heh heh
default : break
}
```

By switching on `true` and writing out the entire boolean condition we break the bounds of pattern-matching and reenter the world of normal expressions.